# Lotus Notes BASIC on RDS 2012. An unexpected network error occurred

Tags: email, lotus-notes

We recentlly install Lotus Notes BASIC R9.0.1 FP2 on a Windows Terminal Server 2012.

```
1) Program File are installed on the TSE

2) Data File are installed on a san server with a mapped drive
```

It works fine until the user leave his Lotus Notes Client in Stand by near 30 min.

When he want to use is mail. I have the message "An unexpected network error occurred". And the Lotus Client Crash

Accessing the Data file with explorer is ok !

I don't understand ?

---

I know that it is not a supported version. Don't understand why ! But i see several people running Lotus Notes on TSE without issue.

So i am searching for a solution ...

Thanks for your precision

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:
  Requirement for Citrix ICA client 
Deploying Lotus Notes clients on Terminal Server Edition or Windows Server with Terminal Services alone, without Citrix XenApp ICA client, is not a supported configuration. An enhancement request SPR# RBOD6WG3MP has been submitted to Quality Engineering requesting support for installing and running a Notes client on Windows Terminal Services without the Citrix ICA client . 
Currently, there are no plans to change this functionality.

Mapped drives and Notes is not a good idea. if there is a small interrupt in the connection between the server and the mapped drive, notes dies.